# I Accidentally Deleted the Launcher

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sd-card, boot, launcher

I was making some tests on my android phone and I accidentally deleted the launcher from the system partition and I forgot to copy the new one to the system partition again, and the phone doesn't show anything, just the status bar and I can't enter or run anything.

I tryed to send the launcher's apk using bluetooth, but neither other android phone nor windows 8.1 can't send any file to the phone, even if the phone is paired with both devices.

Is there any way to run the Play Store to install the launcher or to install the launcher from the SD card?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a launcher on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store) and remotely install it that way. Then reboot the phone after it installs. Once the phone reboots it should prompt you to pick a launcher and then you can go from there.

So for instance if you want the [Google Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher).

Then click on the Install button and select the device. As long as the device is online and signed into your account, it will install for you automatically.

Edit. Forgot to say this. You can do this from another device, just have to do it through the browser and not the app. Or since you said Windows 8.1 I assume thats a desktop/laptop. You can do it on there as well.

Edit 2. Adding on what @Izzy commented. You can download the apk for google's launcher from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/themes-apps/apk-google-launcher-lollipop-version-t2941187). Then sideload via adb, using the command `adb install </folder/nameof.apk>`.

Comment: Beat me to it – yepp, that's exactly what solves it (+1). With the device not connected to GPlay, `adb install` is an alternative if you got hold of some launcher `.apk` :)

Comment: Was about to re-edit my answer to include that as well. But was looking for where he could download an apk to a launcher to sideload like that. Lol

Comment: I can help you with the latter: see my list of [Home Replacements](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher), many of them offer an `.apk` download (blue icon with an arrow pointing down).

Comment: I tried that, but the device is not detected on Windows. Is there a way to install it from SD? I don't have access from the device to anything, that includes the Play Store. One more thing, I have other device of the same model, it turns on but does not shows anything on the screen, the screen backlight turns on, but nothing is shown, just a "black screen". What can I do? by the way, both phones are iRulu Universe 2 and I got both from a gift.

Answer (score 1):

What type of android are you using? My advice if google play store can still be used, use the keyword launcher to find thelauncher you want, then restart.

Comment: I did the same thing. Once I went to General Settings -> General -> Accounts & Sync and signed in, there were lots of notifications that took me to the Google Play Store.