# Problem in turning on a phone without any launcher?

Tags: launcher

The only launcher of my phone which is a note 3 samsung china version was deleted and now it is turn off, how can I do with it?

Comment: See [I Accidentally Deleted the Launcher](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/115888)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the device is still configured with your Google account, some network (WiFi or mobile data) is enabled by default, and you can turn it on (though not being brought to the homescreen as it doesn't exist):

- turn on the device and let it boot up
- on another device (e.g. your PC), point your browser to the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps), and log in with your Google account
- still in the browser, select any launcher/homescreen app you like, then click the "install" button

After a short delay, the selected launcher should be installed on your device. Give it a few minutes, then tap the "home" button. If nothing happens, give it a few more minutes. Once the app is installed, this should launch your new homescreen app.